# conditional radio button angularjs

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, checked, angularjs-ng-checked

I am trying to get radio button checked  or un checked based on flag status, though it is alsways checked for first radio button ffor below code

```
<label class="col-md-5 control-label">Active?</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="activeFlag" id="active" value="active" ng-checked="{{flag}}"> True
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="activeFlag" id="deactive" value="deactive" ng-checked="{{!flag}}"> False
        </label>
    </div>
```

Here flag can be false or true based on input value.
"Inspect Element" shows as below:

```
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="activeFlag" id="active" value="active" ng-checked="true" checked="checked"> True
                        </label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="activeFlag" id="deactive" value="deactive" ng-checked="false"> False
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

I dont have idea from where that checked attribute pops up . Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ngChecked` expects an Angular expression - so remove the `{{}}`

```
ng-checked="!flag"
```

Comment: it worked... thanks... though i cant understand why it was adding checked attribute all by itself, also it was giving corrent output for ng-checked as well, so it never occured to me that i need to remove {{}}.